# incompatible pointer type while assigning pointer to array of integers

Tags: c, pointers

I am typing this program and assigning the address of an array of 10 integers to a pointer pointing to a array of 2 integers.

```
int (*a)[2],i;
int a1[10]={1,12,3,4,5};
a=a1;
printf("%d",*(*a+1));
```

The output is 12 but I am also getting a warning:

> "assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]"

Why am I getting this warning and how to get rid of this warning?

Comment: a is a array of pointers.

Comment: @elyashiv Check that declaration again... `a` is a pointer to an array of integers, not an array of pointers.

Comment: you just need to add `&` before `a1` in expression `a = a1;`, so it will be `a = &a1;`.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems:

1. `a` is a pointer to an array of *two* integers, but you try to assign it from an array of *ten* integers.
2. `a` is a *pointer* to an array, and `a1` is not.

First change `a` to be a pointer to an array of ten integers:

```
int (*a)[10];
```

Then assign to it a pointer to the array:

```
a = &a1;
```

Comment: I'm always wondering why these kind of questions arise. Can't peope read the warning? Cant they hammer the type into cdecl.org if they have a doubt? This is *soooo* basic (and even more importantly, trivially resolvable with a minimal amount of effort...)

Comment: ...do they _know_ about cdecl?

Answer (score 1):

> Why am i getting this warning

Because `a1` is an `int[10]`, so it decays into `int *` when assigned to a pointer, but `a` is of type `int (*)[2]` - those are incompatible types.

> how to get rid of this warning?

Declare `a` as `int (*a)[10]`, then use the address-of (`&`) operator:

```
a = &a1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need compile time bound checking?

If that's not the case, why don't you:

```
int *a, i;
int a1[10]={1,12,3,4,5};
a=&a1[0]; 
printf("%d",a[1]);
```